# How to write a average formula in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate average, but i am getting an run-time error. Here is my code..

```
lastrowcell = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("F1").Value = "High+Low/2"
For n = 2 To lastrowcell
    Range(Cells(n, 6)).Formula = "=average(" & Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 3)).Address(False, False) & ")"
Next
```

Can anyone show what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you need a Next n not just a Next.

Comment: No its not working... I am getting run-time error at `Range(Cells(n, 6)).Formula = "=average(" & Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 3)).Address(False, False) & ")"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop, Excel is smart enough to fill the entire thing in one go:

```
lastrowcell = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("F1").Value = "High+Low/2"
Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=AVERAGE(B6:C6)"
```

The 6 will be incremented in each row

If you want the last row though, its always better to come from the bottom up unless you are specifically looking for the first blank:

```
lastrowcell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).end(xlup).row
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

`Range(Cells(n, 6))`

is not correct syntax for `Range` property. When there is only one parameter, it should be string. Instead you can use:

`Cells(n, 6)`

or

`Range("F" & n)`.